# How to do styling on buttons on a message box pop-up

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I want to know how can I style buttons on MsgBox pop-up??

I have the following code right now

It works fine but I'm unable to do any styling to the buttons. Like I want "YES" button to be blue in color & rounded corners and "NO" button be red in color.

```js
afterrender: function() {

  MsgBox.show({
    msgs: [{
      type: 'info',
      msg: Lang.getCustomFrameworkMessage('Do you want to search google?')
    }],
    buttons: MsgBox.YESNO,
    fn: function(buttonId) {
      if (buttonId === "yes") {
        var redirect = 'https://google.com'
        window.open(redirect);

      }
    }
  }).setBodyStyle('font-size: 18px; text-align: center').setSize(600, 50);
}
```

FYI,
I do not (or cannot) have a css file since I'm working with Extjs within an application that only supports Extjs, so all the styling needs to be done with the extjs script only.

@Fabio Barros:

I'm getting the buttons as follows: [image]

I added padding to the button text as well like this:

```
'   .x-message-box-yes .x-btn-inner, '+
                 '   .x-message-box-no .x-btn-inner { '+
                 '       color: white !important;'+
                 '           padding: 2px !important; '+
                 '       font-weight: bold !important;'+
                 '       font-size: 12px !important;'+
```

But still unable to get the text placed in the center of the button. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot have CSS added from a file or altering the css in the page,i used Narendra answer and create another solution who creates its own css style:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {


        //Create a new Style for the bottons
        var myStyle = document.createElement("STYLE");
        myStyle.innerHTML =
                 '   .x-message-box-no, '+
                 '   .x-message-box-yes { '+
                 '       border-radius: 1em !important; '+
                 '           padding: 3px !important; '+
                 '   } '+
                 '    .x-message-box-yes { '+
                 '       background: blue !important; '+
                 '   } '+
                 '   .x-message-box-no { '+
                 '       background: red !important; '+
                 '   } '+
                 '   .x-message-box-yes .x-btn-inner, '+
                 '   .x-message-box-no .x-btn-inner { '+
                 '       color: white !important;'+
                 '       font-weight: bold !important;'+
                 '   } ';

        //Add it to the head of the document
        var bodyClass = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        bodyClass.insertBefore(myStyle, bodyClass.childNodes[2]);

        //Change the message buttons cls
        Ext.MessageBox.msgButtons.yes.cls = 'x-message-box-yes';
        Ext.MessageBox.msgButtons.no.cls = 'x-message-box-no';

        Ext.Msg.show({
            title: 'Info',
            msg: 'Do you want to search google?',
            buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
            fn: function (buttonId) {
                if (buttonId === "yes") {
                    window.open('https://google.com');
                }
            }
        }).setBodyStyle('font-size: 18px; text-align: center').setSize(300, 50);
    }
});
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Please see my update in the question above regarding padding in the button text.

Comment: It should work, check out this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2km8

Answer (score 1):

For this you can create your own custom message box or override the [`Ext.window.MessageBox`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/api/Ext.window.MessageBox.html). `MessageBox` have method `makeButton`, so you need add your css or styling whatever you want for `Yes` or `No` buttons.

In this **[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2kjf)**, I have created a demo using creating custom message box.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.define('MyMsg', {

            extend: 'Ext.window.MessageBox',

            makeButton: function (btnIdx) {
                var btnId = this.buttonIds[btnIdx];
                return new Ext.button.Button({
                    handler: this.btnCallback,
                    itemId: btnId,
                    cls: (Ext.isArray(this.cls) ? this.cls[0] : this.cls) + '-' + btnId,
                    scope: this,
                    text: this.buttonText[btnId],
                    minWidth: 75
                });
            },
        });

        var MsgBox = new MyMsg();

        MsgBox.show({
            title: 'Info',
            msg: 'Do you want to search google?',
            buttons: MsgBox.YESNO,
            fn: function (buttonId) {
                if (buttonId === "yes") {
                    window.open('https://google.com');
                }
            }
        }).setBodyStyle('font-size: 18px; text-align: center').setSize(300, 50);
    }
});
```